# What to do if we have same element name as follows while parsing that xml file using Simpleframework

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

What to do if we have same element name as follows while parsing that xml file using Simpleframework ?

```
<CCCC_Project>
    <timestamp>Wed Jun 05 15:00:27 2013</timestamp>-
    <project_summary>
        <number_of_modules level="0" value="1" />
        <lines_of_code level="0" value="3" /> lines_of_code_per_module
        <level="0" value="3.000" />
        <McCabes_cyclomatic_complexity level="0" value="0" />
        <McCabes_cyclomatic_complexity_per_module level="0" value="0.000" />
        <lines_of_comment level="0" value="0" />
        <lines_of_comment_per_module level="0" value="0.000" />
        <lines_of_code_per_line_of_comment level="0" value="------" />
        <McCabes_cyclomatic_complexity_per_line_of_comment level="0" value="------" />
        <IF4 level="0" value="0" />
        <IF4_per_module level="0" value="0.000" />
        <IF4_visible level="0" value="0" />
        <IF4_visible_per_module level="0" value="0.000" />
        <IF4_concrete level="0" value="0" />
        <IF4_concrete level="0.000" value="0" />
        <rejected_lines_of_code level="0" value="0" />
    </project_summary>
```

Comment: Where is the xml file?

Comment: Is this giving you an error/exception? Do you mean `IF4_concreate` is repeated twice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@ElementList(inline=true, entry="IF4_concrete")
List<IF_concrete> list;
```